# Why am I permanent banned from chat?

Tags: support

I am unable to access chat. Why am I permanent banned from chat? How am I supposed to communicate with moderators?

Answer (score 8):

You are not..exactly.... banned from *chat*.

You are currently suspended on Cog Sci for 244 more days. As this is the site you selected as your chat parent site, you are banned from chat for the remainder of that suspension.

If you have need of chat, your parent site can be changed, although for now I'm going to leave that for you to discuss with SE.

Please feel free to use the "Contact Us" link at the bottom of the page to do so.

Comment: Ok why don't you just let Jon answer

Comment: @caseyr547 because you're more likely to get a rapid response via "contact us" than hoping Jon happens by our meta.

Comment: Wax your funny another person might buy that but we both know of ways of getting his attention

Comment: @wax Who is Jon?

Comment: @ElberichSchneider Assumably Jon Ericson, an SE Community Manager and former mod of BH

Comment: @wax Thank you.

Comment: @caseyr547: Just curious - What happened on CogSci.SE? Based on your activity, it looks like you were pushing the envelope a bit; but certainly nothing that would warrant a suspension.